# "The following classes could not be instantiated " Whenever i add a library

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

i'm trying to add some library in my application like  `me.itangqi.waveloadingview.WaveLoadingView` from : [Github](https://github.com/tangqi92/WaveLoadingView) The first time works well but after first **RUN** I have this error :

> The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - me.itangqi.waveloadingview.WaveLoadingView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

I already tried  **Clean/Rebuild** but still the same ( doesn't work ).

[image: Error picture]

My build.Gradle :

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
   android {
   compileSdkVersion 25
   buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
   defaultConfig {
       applicationId "maa.maxbattery_batterypowersave"
       minSdkVersion 15
       targetSdkVersion 25
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
       testInstrumentationRunner       "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
               }
            }
      }

  dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-  core:2.2.2',  {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
     compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
     compile 'me.itangqi.waveloadingview:library:0.3.5'
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
```

My Style.xml :

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
         <item name="colorPrimary">#262626</item>
         <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#262626</item>
         <item name="colorAccent">#262626</item>
    </style>
```